# The program loops twice when I only need it to loop once

Tags: python, while-loop

I am trying to code a main menu that launches the game. So, if I try to write "exit" immediately after having run the program without going into "credits", the program quits. However, when I run the program and type "credits" and then "exit". For some reason, it needs me to write "exit" again in order for the program to actually quit.

```
def main_menu():

    main_menu_loop_check = False

    while main_menu_loop_check == False:

        main_menu_layout()

        chosen_option = input("What would you like to do: ")
        normalised_user_input = normalise_input(chosen_option)

        if "start" in normalised_user_input:
            main()
        elif "credits" in normalised_user_input:
            credits_scene()
        elif "exit" in normalised_user_input:
            main_menu_loop_check = True
            print(main_menu_loop_check)
            break
        else:
            print("Invalid option")

def main_menu_layout():
    menu_name = ["  _____ _                  _____                    _ _            __        __     ", " |_   _(_)_ __ ___   ___  |_   _| __ __ ___   _____| | | ___ _ __  \ \      / /   _ ", "   | | | | '_ ` _ \ / _ \   | || '__/ _` \ \ / / _ \ | |/ _ \ '__|  \ \ /\ / / | | |", "   | | | | | | | | |  __/   | || | | (_| |\ V /  __/ | |  __/ |      \ V  V /| |_| |", "   |_| |_|_| |_| |_|\___|   |_||_|  \__,_| \_/ \___|_|_|\___|_|       \_/\_/  \__,_|"]

    menu_start = "{   Start Game  }"
    menu_credits = "{   Credits   }"
    menu_exit = "{    Exit   }"

    print()
    for w in menu_name:
        print(w)
    print()
    print(menu_start.center(85), menu_credits.center(85), menu_exit.center(85), sep='\n\n\n')

main_menu()
```

I just want it to quit when writing "exit" once after entering the credits.

Comment: can't run this as `normalise_input` is not defined. Please provide a working Minimal Reproducible Example. Anyway, after bypassing those definitions I didn't encounter your issue...

Comment: To properly answer this question we would need to see the code for credits_scene(). Though my guess would be that typing exit during the credits merely exits that function, you would need return a value from that function that indicates whether the user wanted to exit and break in that case.